# Jenkins is running on AWS ec2-instance and github is failing to send webhook to it

Tags: jenkins, github-webhook

My jenkins is running on ec2 instance. I have set up webhook on github for one of repos. I could connect to this repo from Jenkins and clone/checkout the code and perform builds manually. However, webhook is failing to deliver the payload and the error message that i always receive is 
"We couldn’t deliver this payload: Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Has anyone came across similar problem? where should i check to find the root cause of this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Best regards,
Amit Joshi

I have checked the security groups associate with the ec2 instance on which jenkins is installed. the security groups allow all kind of traffic on all the ports. both ingress and egress.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a root cause and did not able to solve this issue. However, when i used Ubuntu ec2 instance, it worked perfectly. The jenkins installed on ubuntu instance is able to receive github webhooks. So, there must be something that is wrong with AWS MI ec2 instances that it does not allow webhooks to reach jenkins.